# Seeking java code to convert from DLTM (EPSG 3997) to WGS 84 coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, java

I want a Java function where I can pass WGS 84 X and Y and then return corresponding DLTM values.

I was able to convert to DLTM using ArcGIS JavaScript client SDK, but couldn't get the formula to do the conversion manually.

I expect a function or formula for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished using the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) library.

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3997");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory );
Polygon polygon = (Polygon) reader.read(
    "Polygon ((-7084053.31052524503320456 55154.66467198336613365, -6929233.19916529208421707 106438.82655996795801912, -6879884.28866930678486824 39672.65353598800720647, -6931168.45055729150772095 -26609.70663999210228212, -7089375.25185324344784021 -36769.77644798904657364, -7089375.25185324344784021 -36769.77644798904657364, -7089375.25185324344784021 -36769.77644798904657364, -7084053.31052524503320456 55154.66467198336613365))");

System.out.println(polygon.toString());

MathTransform mTrans = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(polygon, mTrans);
System.out.println(transformed.toText());
```

produces the following output:

```
POLYGON ((-7084053.310525245 55154.664671983366, -6929233.199165292 106438.82655996796, -6879884.288669307 39672.65353598801, -6931168.4505572915 -26609.706639992102, -7089375.251853243 -36769.77644798905, -7089375.251853243 -36769.77644798905, -7089375.251853243 -36769.77644798905, -7084053.310525245 55154.664671983366))
POLYGON ((0.3012904315288025 -0.02297590936861, 0.5840514946046402 0.644311128809204, 0.2181073132042753 0.8649713254541286, -0.1459962911019753 0.6367994063659099, -0.2008372777127641 -0.0452727900026765, -0.2008372777127641 -0.0452727900026765, -0.2008372777127641 -0.0452727900026765, 0.3012904315288025 -0.02297590936861))
```